# Re-loading Dynamic RadioButtonList on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an application where different kinds of survey questions are pulled from a database. 
The first kind I am implementing is a list of questions each with four radio buttons to choose from.

My code for creating the radio button lists and mark up dynamically is

```
  protected void ProcessData(DataTable question, DataTable answers)
    {


        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in question.Rows)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl rowDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            rowDiv.Attributes["class"] = "classRowDiv";
            panel1.Controls.Add(rowDiv);

            HtmlGenericControl questionDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            questionDiv.Attributes["class"] = "classQuestionDiv";
            questionDiv.ID = "questionDiv" + i.ToString();
            rowDiv.Controls.Add(questionDiv);

            Label questionLabel = new Label();
            questionLabel.Attributes["class"] = "classQuestionLabelDiv";
            if (row[2].ToString() == "Radio button")
            {
                questionLabel.Text = row[3].ToString();

                rowDiv.Controls.Add(questionLabel);


                HtmlGenericControl radioDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                radioDiv.Attributes["class"] = "classRadioDiv";
                radioDiv.ID = "radioDiv" + i.ToString();
                rowDiv.Controls.Add(radioDiv);

                RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();


                rbl.ID = "List" + i.ToString();
                radioDiv.Controls.Add(rbl);
                rbl.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;

                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = "<hr />";
                panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);


                DataRow rowA;
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
                {
                    rowA = answers.Rows[j];
                    ListItem button = new ListItem(rowA[2].ToString(), j.ToString());

                    button.Attributes["class"] = "radioStyle";
                    rbl.Items.Add(button);

                }


                i++;
            }

        }


    }
```

The problem I am having is actually getting the selected values of the buttons. I have come to understand from reading around that dynamically created controls must be re-loaded with the same ID after a postback but I do not fully understand how to achieve this as the amount of radio buttons created is dependent on the result set from the database.

Comment: Put `ProcessData` in the `Page_Load` event outside of a `!IsPostBack`. `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { ProcessData(); }`

Comment: I have done that however I then get errors saying multiple divs with the same ID have been created.

Comment: Try to move `i++` outside the `if (row[2].ToString() == "Radio button")`. If row 2 is not a radiobutton `i` will remain the same and thus create duplicate id's